# Mysql - JPA no insert into thrid table Many to Many

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have Many-To-Many relation in my project, i can write in my two Entities table, the relational table does not get anything written.

EspecificacionEscenario Class:

```
public class EspecificacionEscenario implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "idespecificacionEscenario")
private Integer idespecificacionEscenario;
@Column(name = "codigo")
private String codigo;
@Column(name = "fecha")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fecha;
@Column(name = "nombreProceso")
private String nombreProceso;
@Column(name = "nombreEscenario")
private String nombreEscenario;
@Column(name = "objetivoEscenario")
private String objetivoEscenario;
@Column(name = "lugarEscenario")
private String lugarEscenario;
@Column(name = "recursoEscenario")
private String recursoEscenario;
@Column(name = "restriccionEscenario")
private String restriccionEscenario;
@Column(name = "actoresEscenario")
private String actoresEscenario;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "especificacionEscenarioList", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Elicitacion> elicitacionList;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "especificacionEscenarioList", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Episodio> episodioList;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "especificacionEscenarioList", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Educcion> educcionList;
```

Episodio class:

```
public class Episodio implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "idepisodio")
private Integer idepisodio;
@Column(name = "codigo")
private String codigo;
@Column(name = "objetivoEpisodio")
private String objetivoEpisodio;
@Column(name = "descripcionEpisodio")
private String descripcionEpisodio;
@Column(name = "recursosEpisodio")
private String recursosEpisodio;
@Column(name = "restriccionEpisodio")
private String restriccionEpisodio;
@Column(name = "actor")
private String actor;
@JoinTable(name = "especificacionEscenarioEpisodio", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "idepisodio", referencedColumnName = "idepisodio")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "idespecificacionEscenario", referencedColumnName = "idespecificacionEscenario")})
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<EspecificacionEscenario> especificacionEscenarioList;
```

Main code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EpisodioDao episodioDao = new EpisodioDao();
    EspecificacionEscenarioDao escenarioDao = new EspecificacionEscenarioDao();
    Episodio episodio = new Episodio();
    episodio.setCodigo("e01");
    episodio.setDescripcionEpisodio("descripcion episodio");
    EspecificacionEscenario ee = new EspecificacionEscenario();
    ee.setCodigo("ee-01");
    List<Episodio> listaE = new ArrayList<>();
    listaE.add(episodio);
    ee.setEpisodioList(listaE);
    episodioDao.registrarEpisodio(episodio);
    System.exit(0);

}
```

when doing the persistence in the entities the information is saved automatically, but in the table third table it does not insert the primary keys.

Comment: You set the (BIDIRECTIONAL) relation at both sides did you? Don't think you did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added CascadeType.ALL on Episodio as it is the owner of this relation.

Following code may help you. I have tested with spring data jpa.

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
public class Episodio implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idepisodio")
    private Integer idepisodio;

    @Column(name = "codigo")
    private String codigo;

    @Column(name = "objetivoEpisodio")
    private String objetivoEpisodio;

    @Column(name = "descripcionEpisodio")
    private String descripcionEpisodio;

    @Column(name = "recursosEpisodio")
    private String recursosEpisodio;

    @Column(name = "restriccionEpisodio")
    private String restriccionEpisodio;

    @Column(name = "actor")
    private String actor;
    @JoinTable(name = "especificacionEscenarioEpisodio",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "idepisodio", referencedColumnName = "idepisodio")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "idespecificacionEscenario", referencedColumnName = "idespecificacionEscenario")})
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<EspecificacionEscenario> especificacionEscenarioList;

}




@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
public class EspecificacionEscenario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idespecificacionEscenario")
    private Integer idespecificacionEscenario;

    @Column(name = "codigo")
    private String codigo;

    @Column(name = "fecha")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fecha;

    @Column(name = "nombreProceso")
    private String nombreProceso;

    @Column(name = "nombreEscenario")
    private String nombreEscenario;

    @Column(name = "objetivoEscenario")
    private String objetivoEscenario;

    @Column(name = "lugarEscenario")
    private String lugarEscenario;

    @Column(name = "recursoEscenario")
    private String recursoEscenario;

    @Column(name = "restriccionEscenario")
    private String restriccionEscenario;

    @Column(name = "actoresEscenario")
    private String actoresEscenario;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "especificacionEscenarioList", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Episodio> episodioList;

}


EspecificacionEscenario especificacionEscenario = new EspecificacionEscenario();
especificacionEscenario.setCodigo("ee-01");

List<EspecificacionEscenario> especificacionEscenarios = new ArrayList<>();
especificacionEscenarios.add(especificacionEscenario);


Episodio episodio = new Episodio();
episodio.setCodigo("e01");
episodio.setDescripcionEpisodio("descripcion episodio");
episodio.setEspecificacionEscenarioList(especificacionEscenarios);

episodioRepo.save(episodio);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works, I'm a newbie in JPA, thanks for specifying the mandatory entity. Is it possible to change the madatory entity?

Comment: Yes, Generally, @JoinColumn indicates that the entity is the owner of the relationship & mappedBy indicates that the entity is the inverse of the relationship.